# Confused about Scala Singleton object

Tags: scala

I'm a java programer and learning Scalanow. In Java a singleton object means that can only one of this type object exists in the whole JVM. But in Scala how could I create two singleton objects under same type, for example I could created two singleton objects in the same class type Seq:

```
val s1 = Seq("aa","bb")
val s2 = Seq("aa","bb","cc")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit different. 
Read documentation: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html.

In your example you create a value of type Seq. It not a singleton!
Here is example for singleton :

```
object Blah {
  def sum(l: List[Int]): Int = l.sum
}
```

This is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

While you read through the documentation pointed by @Pavel, it's worthwhile to point that:

`val s1 = Seq("aa","bb")`

is not creating any singleton. Rather it is invoking the `apply` method on an abstract superclass of `Seq` which returns an `instance`.